# iPad Digital-AV-Adapter causes Border on TV

Tags: ipad, frame

i need to develop an application providing TV-Out support.

i noticed, that the displayed Window on the TV always has a 40px border on all sides. when i start a movie in youtube however, this borders disappear.

so i currently wonder what to do here.

i CAN access that frames by using negative frame origins, but - of course - the resulution i work with will become somthing like 1300x740 or something instead of 1280x720.

Now i know that i could zoom the views - but this seems to be quite ugly to me.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, refining the frame with way-too-big dimensions did it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to remove the inset is to set the external `UIScreen`'s `overscanCompensation` property:

```
    secondScreen.overscanCompensation = UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetApplicationFrame;
```